# How can I convert a JSON string to something readable?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON string somethink like this:

```
[{"cityId":0,
  "name":"Test",
  "contents":[]
 }]
```

When I display this using the AngularJS {{ }} notation then it gives me something like:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Is there a way that I could make this a bit more readable. The screen is for admin purposes so it need not be any particular format. Just something that would show better than what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is builtin filter for this: `{{ obj | json }}`

More info about json filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json